# Makefile listing the dependencies

Tags: makefile

In below snippet of Makefile the normal way of makefile behave is when foo.o has dependency listed here like /tmp/foo.o: abc.o xyz.o lmn.o etc then while parsing make goes to the rule which list how to make the dependency (abc.o xyz.o lmn.o) but here the target /tmp/foo.o has listed no dependency even then how the next line executed or it simply ignored.

Please explain this as soon as possible that how and why that line (%.o: $$(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h) executed. Any body help is highly appreciated . I need it because of my lecture on make file.

.SECONDEXPANSION:

/tmp/foo.o:

%.o: $$(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h
        @echo $^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a peculiar makefile. It appears that the person who wrote it does not understand Make very well.

The use of `SECONDEXPANSION` causes the prerequisite list:

```
$$(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h
```

to be expanded twice; first to this:

```
$(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h
```

and then to this:

```
foo/%.c bar/%.c foo.h
```

**This use of `SECONDEXPANSION` accomplishes nothing.** We could just as well write the rule like this:

```
%.o: $(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h
    @echo $^
```

or this:

```
%.o: foo/%.c bar/%c foo.h
    @echo $^
```

In any case, this is a pattern rule. If you attempt to build `snaf.o` (and there is no explicit rule for the target `snaf.o`), then Make will consider this rule, matching the stem `snaf`, so that the rule is equivalent to this:

```
snaf.o: foo/snaf.c bar/snaf.c foo.h
    @echo $^
```

**None of this has any bearing on the target `/tmp/foo.o`**, since the pattern rule will not match a target that has a slash in it. (If the pattern rule were `/tmp/%.o: ...`, that would be a different story.) So the two rules do not really interact, and the author's intention is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir!!!!!!!!!!!!                                     but my question was if a target has an empty list and no explicit rule then the next line following a pattern rule, like in this case "the target foo.o : has no dependency list and no explicit rule " then the make will automatically goes for %.o: rule or it ignores. This is what I want to know please explain?

Comment: @Beta, as for `This is a peculiar makefile.`. This makefile is from make doc: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html, paragraph **Secondary Expansion of Implicit Rules**

Comment: yes sir !!!! It is from the make docs but in the lecture it the reference point. So please explain the above question that if a target has no dependency list and no explicit rule and a pattern rule then make considers the pattern rule for the target automatically or there is some other mechanism for this.